# Rolling a fair dice

Tags: probability

This is a basic probability question.

We roll a fair six-faced dice. We roll it repeatedly until the sum of the numbers cast up to that point is a multiple of six. What is the expected number of throws?

Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Showing us that is the way to get help. I see that you have just asked two questions one right after the other showing your work in neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

At every throw the probability of reaching a sum that is a multiple of $6$ is $\frac16$.

If $n$ is the total of the former throws then observe that the set $\{n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5,n+6\}$ contains exactly one element that is a multiple of $6$.

So actually you are dealing with a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).